# A certain composition into the elementary symmetric polynomials

Tags: combinatorics, summation, symmetric-polynomials, set-partition, multinomial-coefficients

### Preliminaries

Let $\mathbb{F}$ be a field such that $\operatorname{char}(\mathbb{F})\neq2$.

Let $n$ be a non-zero natural number. Let $\mathbb{F}\left[x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n \right]$ be a polynomial ring in $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n$ over the field $\mathbb{F}$.

Let $m$ be a non-zero natural number. For any $1 \le i \le m$ and $1 \le j \le n$ let $c_{i,j} \in \mathbb{F}$.

For each $1 \le i \le m$ denote $X_{i} \equiv \left( \sum_{j=1}^{n}{c_{i,j}x_{j}} \right)^{2}$ and obtain that $X_{i} \in \mathbb{F}\left[x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n \right]$.

Let $\ell$ be a natural number. The *elementary symmetric polynomials* $e_{\ell}$ in $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_m$ are given by 
$$
e_{\ell}\left(X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_m \right) \equiv
\begin{cases}
1,  & \ell=0 \\\
\displaystyle \sum_{1 \le i_{1} < i_{2} < \cdots < i_{\ell} \le m}{\left(\prod_{k=1}^{\ell}{X_{i_{k}}}\right)}, & 1 \le \ell \le m \\\
0, & m < \ell
\end{cases}
$$

### Problem statement

Find a ("nice", "concise", "low-complexity") algebraic/combinatorial representation of the coefficient of $\prod_{j=1}^{n}{x_{j}^{p_{j}}}$ in the expansion of $e_{\ell}\left(X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_m \right)$ for any $1 \le \ell \le m$, in terms of the $c_{i,j},p_{j}$ and (compositions of) $\ell$.

### My work so far

By direct substitution obtain

$$
\begin{align}
e_{\ell}\left(X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_m \right) & = \displaystyle \sum_{1 \le i_{1} < i_{2} < \cdots < i_{\ell} \le m}{\left(\prod_{k=1}^{\ell}{X_{i_{k}}}\right)} \\
 & = \displaystyle \sum_{1 \le i_{1} < i_{2} < \cdots < i_{\ell} \le m}{\left(\prod_{k=1}^{\ell}{\left( \sum_{j=1}^{n}{c_{i_k,j}x_{j}} \right)^{2}}\right)} \\
 & = \displaystyle \sum_{1 \le i_{1} < i_{2} < \cdots < i_{\ell} \le m}{\left(\prod_{k=1}^{\ell}{\left( \sum_{a=1}^{n}{c_{i_k,a}x_{a}} \right) \left( \sum_{b=1}^{n}{c_{i_k,b}x_{b}} \right)}\right)} \\
 & = \displaystyle \sum_{1 \le i_{1} < i_{2} < \cdots < i_{\ell} \le m}{\left(\prod_{k=1}^{\ell}{\left( \sum_{a=1}^{n}{c_{i_k,a}x_{a}} \right)}\right) \left(\prod_{k=1}^{\ell}{ \left( \sum_{b=1}^{n}{c_{i_k,b}x_{b}} \right)}\right)}  \\
 & = \displaystyle \sum_{1 \le i_{1} < i_{2} < \cdots < i_{\ell} \le m}{\left(\prod_{k=1}^{\ell}{\left( \sum_{a_k=1}^{n}{c_{i_k,a_k}x_{a_k}} \right)}\right) \left(\prod_{k=1}^{\ell}{ \left( \sum_{b_k=1}^{n}{c_{i_k,b_k}x_{b_k}} \right)}\right)} \\
& = \displaystyle \sum_{1 \le i_{1} < i_{2} < \cdots < i_{\ell} \le m}{\left(\sum_{a_{1}=1}^{n}{} \cdots \sum_{a_{\ell}=1}^{n}{}{\left( \prod_{k=1}^{\ell}{c_{i_k,a_k}x_{a_k}} \right)}\right) \left(\sum_{b_{1}=1}^{n}{} \cdots \sum_{b_{\ell}=1}^{n}{}{ \left( \prod_{k=1}^{\ell}{c_{i_k,b_k}x_{b_k}} \right)}\right)} \\
 & = \displaystyle \sum_{1 \le i_{1} < i_{2} < \cdots < i_{\ell} \le m}{\left(\sum_{1 \le a_{1} , a_{2} , \cdots , a_{\ell} \le n}^{}{\left( \prod_{k=1}^{\ell}{c_{i_k,a_k}x_{a_k}} \right)}\right) \left(\sum_{1 \le b_{1} , b_{2} , \cdots , b_{\ell} \le n}^{}{ \left( \prod_{k=1}^{\ell}{c_{i_k,b_k}x_{b_k}} \right)}\right)} \\
\end{align}
$$
Now Let us focus on just $\displaystyle \left(\sum_{1 \le a_{1} , a_{2} , \cdots , a_{\ell} \le n}^{}{\left( \prod_{k=1}^{\ell}{c_{i_k,a_k}x_{a_k}} \right)}\right)$. I'd like to write that 
$$
\begin{align}
\displaystyle \sum_{1 \le a_{1} , a_{2} , \cdots , a_{\ell} \le n}^{}{\left( \prod_{k=1}^{\ell}{c_{i_k,a_k}x_{a_k}} \right)} & = \displaystyle \sum_{q_1+q_2+\cdots+q_n=\ell\\0 \le q_1,0 \le q_2,\ldots,0 \le q_n}^{}{\left(\binom{\ell}{q_1,q_2,\cdots,q_n}\left( \text{something to do with }c_{i_k,a_k} \right) \left( \prod_{j=1}^{n}{x_{j}^{q_j}} \right)\right)} \\
\end{align}
$$
But now there is no "memory" of exactly which $q_j$ indecies from $\{a_1,\ldots,a_{\ell} \}$ are equal to $j$ in each iteration of the sum. This is a problem because we need to match $q_j$ indecies from $\{i_1,\ldots,i_{\ell} \}$ to $j$ in order to have the right idea about that something to do with the $c_{i_k,a_k}$s. How one may overcome this?

Comment: It's hard to follow ! Could you give an example in, say the finite field with $9$ elements ?

Comment: @JeanMarie I don't see how a concrete example could help here, as I'll do the exact same steps. Let me refer to the aligned equations by row and explain. Row 3: use two different dummy variables $a,b$ to make clear how to expand that square. Row 4: apply the identity $\prod_{i}{a_{i}b_{i}}=\prod_{i}{a_{i}\prod_{i}{}b_{i}}$. Row 5: again introduce $\ell$ dummy variables $a_k,1 \le k \le \ell$ and $\ell$ dummy variables $b_k,1 \le k \le \ell$ to make clear how one shoud expand those two products. Row 6: expand the two products and rearrange. I'll add a row between 5 and 6 to make things clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\mathcal{F}_{l, n}^{(q_1, q_2, \cdots, q_n)} = \{f:[l] \rightarrow [n] : |f^{-1}(i)| = q_i, i\in [n]\}$ for $q_i\geq 0$ and $\sum_{i=1}^lq_i = n$. Then the $\binom{\ell}{q_1,q_2,\cdots,q_n}\left( \text{something to do with }c_{i_k,a_k} \right)$ part in your last expression can be replaced with

$\begin{align}\sum_{f\in \mathcal{F}_{l, n}^{(q_1, q_2, \cdots, q_n)}}\prod_{k=1}^l c_{i_k, a_{f(k)}}\end{align}$. Since $|\mathcal{F}_{l, n}^{(q_1, q_2, \cdots, q_n)}| = \binom{\ell}{q_1,q_2,\cdots,q_n}$, you can write $\left( \text{something to do with }c_{i_k,a_k} \right)$ as $E_{f\sim \mathcal{F}_{l, n}^{(q_1, q_2, \cdots, q_n)}} \left[\prod_{k=1}^l c_{i_k, a_{f(k)}}\right]$, where $f$ is chosen from $\mathcal{F}_{l, n}^{(q_1, q_2, \cdots, q_n)}$ uniformly at random.